# cannot convert from view to button error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple android project. its made up of a button that shows another activity. can you please tell me whats wrong with this

> cannot convert from view to button

error in the last line?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b =  findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }
}
```

Comment: people ask questions at their level. There is no need for down voting this question. If you think it is too easy, move along or better yet answer it.

Answer (score 4):

you have to cast view to a button

```
Button b =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: @majid mohebbi so does your problem solved if so don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Every widget from palette is view and need to cast depend on Object behavior

in your scene you need to cast as above @Fast Snail mentioned !

in addition you should use beauty of code like

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    init();
}

//place all initialized objects
private void init()
{
     b =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

}
```